# Mysql get unique records between dates with a specific order

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table

```
    id | item_id | start_date |  end_date  | disc_percent
    1  |  1      | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    2  |  2      | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    3  |  3      | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    4  | 137     | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    5  | 1       | 2016-12-28 | 2016-12-29 |    10
```

and I am running this query:

```
SELECT * 
from onsale 
WHERE  (CURDATE() BETWEEN onsale.start_date 
                      AND onsale.end_date) 
order by onsale.start_date DESC, 
         onsale.end_date ASC
```

I want to get only the first record of each item_id like this:

```
    id | item_id | start_date |  end_date  | disc_percent
    5  |  1      | 2016-12-28 | 2016-12-29 |    10
    2  |  2      | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    3  |  3      | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
    4  | 137     | 2016-12-27 | 2016-12-31 |    50
```

how can I get this result?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: Just read thru the answers recommended,  i dont undestand them

Answer (score 2):

For getting unique record for **item_id**, you should use **group by** clause. **group by** clause returns unique row for a table.

The query will be like this -

```
SELECT * 
from onsale 
WHERE  (CURDATE() BETWEEN onsale.start_date 
                      AND onsale.end_date) group by item_id
order by onsale.start_date DESC, 
         onsale.end_date ASC
```

Comment: group by does not provide the result i expect

Comment: Do you want the result exactly what you mentioned in the table above and also the record of the table will be fixed ?

Comment: `ASC` is optional

Comment: yes i need the exact result  and the records are dinamic

Answer (score 0):

Try This...No aggregation functions needed...

```
select * from (select * from onsale order by start_date desc) onsale group by item_id;
```

**check on sqlfiddle**:-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/218a1/1

Comment: thanks denny your answer work great on the fiddle but i dont undestand why it does not work on my server, the only different thing i notice is the mysql version fiddle = 5.6 my server = 5.7. any ideas?

Comment: @ALDI i also tried on 5.7.successfully execute.there is no trouble on it.check here http://rextester.com/SVGEOV26849

Comment: @ALDI only date different on both result cause you ignore end_date which was past.and today is 30dec.